# ¿Cómo escribo cadenas a un fichero sin añadir un salto de línea final?

Tags: python, archivo

Estoy tratando de escribir unas variables en un csv, pero quiero que cada una se escriba una al lado de otra cuando la abra en excel. Solo se que para saltar de linea se usa el `\n` y así sale en otra celda de abajo, pero quiero saber como puedo pasar de celda lateralmente.

Este es un ejemplo de cuando se escriben una abajo de otra:

```
with open("productos.csv", 'w') as login:
    login.write(introduce_producto +"\n")
    login.write(introduce_precio +"\n")  
    login.write(introduce_marca +"\n")
    login.close()
```

Comment: `close()` es innecesario cuando usas `with open`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En lugar de separarlo con saltos de línea `\n`, separalo con comas `,`.

Usando tu propio ejemplo:

```
with open("productos.csv", 'w') as login:
    login.write("Columna1"+",")
    login.write("Columna2" +",")  
    login.write("Columna3" +",")
```

Verás que al abrir `productos.csv` estarán cada uno en una columna.

Esto es baśico. Luego puedes utilizar incluso módulos más avanzados como [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Comment: Muchas gracias Compañero!

Comment: Y por qué no, si ha sido una buena respuesta además de marcarla como "respuesta correcta", darle una puntuación positiva! Estas son las mejores formas de dar las gracias en StackOverflow! :)