# Como hago un append en un archivo .txt en python

Tags: python

Digamos que tengo una lista grande en un archivo .txt con nombres de puglins de wordpress y quiero añardile este formato a todos los nombres de los plugins de la siguiente manera:
`wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms/`

Estuve leyendo algo al respecto e implementé esta pequeña linea de código, pero no funciona.

```
f = open('wp_plugins.txt', 'a')
f.write('\n' + 'wp-content/plugins/')
# mensaje = f.read()
# print(mensaje)
f.close()
```

Plug-ins:

- wordpress-seo
- really-simple-captcha
- advanced-custom-fields
- contact-form-7
- hello-dolly
- regenerate-thumbnails
- nextgen-gallery
- tinymce-advanced
- all-in-one-seo-pack

Desde ya agradezco su estoica ayuda.

Comment: Tienes ya varias respuestas similares. Una por ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/395652/177597 utilizas otro tipo de filehandle para hacer append y lo tienes ;).

Comment: Guau eso fue rápido! Muchas gracias por los links y por la edición de mi pregunta, me pondré manos a la obra! Saludos programadores 